# Regex find a string only with html tags

Tags: php, regex

Hi I would like to use a regex query which finds all instances of a string which appears within html tags.  The string I am trying to find also appears in attribute tags which I would to avoid from the search.

```
include : <tag>text text  /string to find/ text text </tag>

exclude : <meta content="/string to find/"></meta>
```

Comment: can you please give clear explanation

Comment: use an html parser instead.

Comment: I only have regex for this one.

Comment: Hope that makes more sense

Comment: Give this a try `preg_match("/<\w+>(\/.+)<\/\w+>/", $input_line, $output_array);` Then just grab `$output_array[1]`

Comment: Thanks @Toto that works great!